# How can I make disappear the indent of my caption in Tufte book style?

Tags: tables, captions, margins, tufte

I've some troubles with my `caption` definition in my Tufte book style document. The caption work perfectly fine for `marginfigure` environments while it indent the figure label for `figure`, `margintable` and `table` environments. You can see on the pictures below framed in green what I want as an indent (i.e. nothing) for my caption style and in red what I don't want.

### [image]

You can find my `caption` definition here in my minimal document code under the `CAPTION STYLE` comment divider:

```
\documentclass[justified,notoc,numbers]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

%=======================================================
%                      FOR DEBUG
%=======================================================
\usepackage{lipsum}

%=======================================================
%                      FONT STYLE
%=======================================================
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

%=======================================================
%                       COLORS
%=======================================================
\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}

%=======================================================
%                   CAPTION STYLE
%=======================================================
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  %
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup%
    \@parboxrestore%
    \if@minipage%
      \@setminipage%
    \fi%
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \colorbox{myColor}{\color{white}\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:} \ignorespaces#3\par%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


%=======================================================
%                       GEOMETRY
%=======================================================
\geometry{
  left=15mm,                    % left margin
  textwidth=140mm,              % main text block
  headsep=10mm,
  headheight = 0mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,             % gutter between main text block and margin notes
  marginparwidth=50mm,          % width of margin notes
  bottom = 1.5cm, 
  top = 1.7cm
}

%=======================================================
%                     HEADER/FOOTER
%=======================================================
\pagestyle{fancy}{
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Author Name \& Firstname}
\lhead{\textsc{test} - tex.stackexchange.com}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

}

%=======================================================
%                       DOCUMENT
%=======================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a well indent caption as you can see with a multi line caption it is well justified.}
\end{marginfigure}

\begin{margintable}[2cm]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{This is \textbf{NOT} a well indent caption as you can see with a multi line caption it is not well justified.}
\end{margintable}
\vspace{9cm} %To make it clear
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Once again, this is \textbf{NOT} a well indent caption as you can see with a multi line caption it is not well justified.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1 & 2\\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Once again, this is \textbf{NOT} a well indent caption as you can see with a multi line caption it is not well justified.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'm not really familiar with the `\def` command but I tried my best to get what I wanted as caption style. Does any of you know how to applied this style without any further indent for all my `figure` and `table` environments? What seems weird to me is that the style is well applied for all environments but spacings are still wildly added to some. I know that Tufte book captions' are special so I need to use `\@tufte@caption` to access their style but should I perform that in other places to access the other environments caption styles too?

I use `pdfLaTex` version 2019 as a compiler.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indent is caused by `\JustifyingParindent`.

In `marginfigure` and `margintable` environments, the caption is printed with setting `justified` and `\@tufte@margin@par`. This makes `\JustifyingParindent` has value 0.5pc.

Note that in `marginfigure` and `margintable` environments, the `\caption` does not automatically start a new paragraph. Therefore, in your example, there is no indent before caption of `marginfigure`, but there is an indent before caption of `margintable` (the empty line before `\caption` starts a new paragraph).

```
% Paragraph indentation and separation for marginal text
\newcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.5pt}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
```

In `figure` and `table` environments, the caption is printed with setting `justified`, which sets `\JustifyingParindent` to value 1.0pc.

```
% Paragraph indentation and separation for normal text
\newcommand{\@tufte@reset@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1.0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{1.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\@tufte@reset@par
```

To cancel the indent before `\caption` in both cases, it is sufficient to set `\JustifyingParindent` to zero. The following lines do the job:

```
\setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
```

PS: pc stands for "pica", 1pc = 12pt.